# SunOS last wtmp parse

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that I've been using to parse the wtmp file to add all users time together and strip our erroneous data. This script works wonderfully on my more recent/up-to-date systems. However, I have 1 older system, a Sparc Ultra 3000 running Solaris 8 I believe. This thing is more of a pain in my ass than you know. So, I'm trying to get my users logged in time from it, and format the output like this-

```
bbarret8 316
cchang5 703
ccomanes 2267
ckeefe 24
cmeyer7 82
dbabbini 140
```

The perl script I'm using is here http://pastebin.com/ayN1yMJU

My input looks like this (with many more entry's)-

```
lwoods4   console      :0               Mon Dec 30 14:08 - 14:22  (00:14)
dhesek    console      :0               Mon Dec 30 09:51 - 09:53  (00:01)
lwoods4   console      :0               Sun Dec 29 15:06 - 15:16  (00:09)
dhesek    console      :0               Sun Dec 29 09:26 - 09:30  (00:04)
dhesek    console      :0               Fri Dec 27 16:15 - 16:17  (00:01)
ylin7     console      :0               Fri Dec 27 15:24 - 16:04  (00:40)
lwoods4   console      :0               Fri Dec 27 14:11 - 14:25  (00:13)
lwoods4   console      :0               Fri Dec 27 11:18 - 11:35  (00:17)
dhesek    console      :0               Thu Dec 26 13:21 - 14:38  (01:16)
dhesek    console      :0               Wed Dec 25 14:20 - 14:23  (00:02)
sbrown3   console      :0               Tue Dec 24 14:40 - 14:53  (00:12)
dhesek    console      :0               Tue Dec 24 09:21 - 09:25  (00:04)
sbrown3   console      :0               Mon Dec 23 11:20 - 12:20  (00:59)
ylin7     console      :0               Sun Dec 22 21:44 - 22:00  (00:16)
sbrown3   console      :0               Sat Dec 21 15:05 - 16:18  (01:12)
kwatson2  console      :0               Fri Dec 20 18:41 - 19:03  (00:22)
```

And my output-

```
# ./Varian.wtmp.last.pl 
0 1
jvail1 19
kwatson2 22
mm 1
nmrext0 21
```

Is this because the script is calling the 'last' command on my current system to parse an output file from the Solaris system? They appear to be the same to my eyes, but maybe they're not.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see both outputs. Check match for `+` which is optional now (when parsing days).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %TIMES;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (my($name,$days,$hours,$mins) = /^(\w+).+\((?:(\d+)\+?)?(\d+):(\d+)/) {
        #                                 '+' is optional __^ 

        $TIMES{$name} += 1440 * $days + 60 * $hours + $mins;
    }
}
foreach (sort keys %TIMES) {
    print "$_ $TIMES{$_}\n";
}
__DATA__
lwoods4   console      :0               Mon Dec 30 14:08 - 14:22  (00:14)
dhesek    console      :0               Mon Dec 30 09:51 - 09:53  (00:01)
lwoods4   console      :0               Sun Dec 29 15:06 - 15:16  (00:09)
dhesek    console      :0               Sun Dec 29 09:26 - 09:30  (00:04)
dhesek    console      :0               Fri Dec 27 16:15 - 16:17  (00:01)
ylin7     console      :0               Fri Dec 27 15:24 - 16:04  (00:40)
lwoods4   console      :0               Fri Dec 27 14:11 - 14:25  (00:13)
lwoods4   console      :0               Fri Dec 27 11:18 - 11:35  (00:17)
dhesek    console      :0               Thu Dec 26 13:21 - 14:38  (01:16)
dhesek    console      :0               Wed Dec 25 14:20 - 14:23  (00:02)
sbrown3   console      :0               Tue Dec 24 14:40 - 14:53  (00:12)
dhesek    console      :0               Tue Dec 24 09:21 - 09:25  (00:04)
sbrown3   console      :0               Mon Dec 23 11:20 - 12:20  (00:59)
ylin7     console      :0               Sun Dec 22 21:44 - 22:00  (00:16)
sbrown3   console      :0               Sat Dec 21 15:05 - 16:18  (01:12)
kwatson2  console      :0               Fri Dec 20 18:41 - 19:03  (00:22)
```

output

```
dhesek 88
kwatson2 22
lwoods4 53
sbrown3 143
ylin7 56
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Nothing changed, I get the same exact output as before even with the additional `+` regex.  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by seeing both outputs.  

The intended output is 

`bbarret8 316
cchang5 703
ccomanes 2267`

And the output I'm getting is 
`0 1
jvail1 19
kwatson2 22
mm 1
nmrext0 21`

Comment: Nope, exactly the same. Let me try the eval.in thing.

Comment: @user1732812 proper copy/paste should fix this.

Comment: Okay!  So that eval.in worked with the whole dataset.  One thing I was changed was the `__DATA__` statement.  I wanted/need the script to open the wtmp file so I used `open LAST, "last -f wtmp.dec-2013 |";

my %TIMES;
while (<LAST>) {
    if (my($name,$days,$hours,$mins) = /^(\w+).+\((?:(\d+)\+?)?(\d+):(\d+)/) {
        #                                 '+' is optional __^ 

        $TIMES{$name} += 1440 * $days + 60 * $hours + $mins;
    }
}
foreach (sort keys %TIMES) {
    print "$_ $TIMES{$_}\n";
}`

Apparently that broke something.